# Add custom option in Layered Navigation-Magento

Tags: magento-1.8

Is there any way to add the custom option in the Layered navigation of Magento?

Comment: No. Only attributes can be added to the layered navigation, because custom options are CUSTOM to every product and you don't know whether a product has this option or not.

Answer (score 3):

No there isn't. The layered navigation works with product attributes.
Well...there is always a way, but this would mean to change A LOT many sensitive sections of Magento and I don't think it's worth it. I cannot estimate such a task but for sure it will take more than 1.3 eternities.